# How to debug variable in android?

Tags: android, debugging

I have Googled solution of the issue that I am facing but could not find satisfactory solution.

I want step by step debugging of my app on android device but I have the following issues.

1- I have putted break points on each line of `onResume()` method of `MainActivity` to check the flow of my app, as I run the app in debugging mode on my device the app doesn't show its interface even after execution of all the break points. I want interaction with the app but it shows blank screen and doesn't show button controls.

2- How can I monitor value of a variable while debugging.

Comment: Does your app display anything when you open it up?

Comment: In normal mode it shows all the controls but in debug mode the app doesn't show any thing.

Comment: I use eclipse ADT and debugging works fine. I just enable USB debugging in my phone settings. Have you done this?

Comment: Yes! I also use eclipse ADT and enabled USB debugging in my phone settings as well.

Comment: I havent had a problem like that before. Try using an emulator, if that fails as well then it must be a problem with eclipse

Comment: have you used "Resume (F8)" to continue your execution? otherwise the debugger still holds your programm after the breakpoints and I think `onResume()` is executed before showing the GUI.